# UIScrollView pass dragging to main view

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have the next trouble and hope you could give me advice to handle with it.

I have page controller w/ vertical scrolling. Inside of page view I use a few component one of them is UIScrollView. In order to scroll between pages I should drag anything except this UIScrollView, because ScrollView catch any events and prevent page controller to get them.

**So my question, How is it possible to pass drag event to UIPageControllerView from UIScrollView.**

For example, when scroll content of UISCrollView reach top, it pass dragging so Page controller could change page. And vise versa, if you reach the end of content of UIScrollView next dragging is handled by PageController to change page.

Any advises are appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you want sounds an awful lot like pull to refresh technique, where you pull down the page to get the latest tweets/Facebook posts/lemon pie recipes/whatever. Instead of refreshing, you want that event to trigger a segue to a new page. The default built in one only works for UITableView but there are a lot of libraries that let you use UIScrollView. Here's an example:

http://mt.gomiso.com/2012/03/22/yet-another-pull-to-refresh-library/

You could take them apart and take a look or use them as-is, I can't exactly determine what it is you want.

---

Also you could try to dig in a little further into the following UIScrollView method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
```

Then see what value contentOffset has at that point.

Now if you want to see what that scrollview does from within your UIPageViewController you could implement the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol on your UIPageViewController and set that viewcontroller as the delegate for your UIScrollView:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html

Code will look a bit like this:

.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIPageViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
// The rest of your properties

@end
```

.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad;
{
    // Tell the scrollView you want to be the delegate for it
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
{
    // read self.scrollView.contentOffset and see if it has been pulled out of bounds
    // If it is, do a segue
}
```